# Компиляция приложений: Self-contained или Framework Development

Tags: c#, .net-core

Решил я скомпилировать свою программу (Publish) чтобы использовать на другом компьютере.
Увидел там два режима.

- Self-contained
- Framework Development

Скомпилировал первым получилось примерно 88мб, и ве работает.
Скомпилировал вторым получилось 185кб, и не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы второе работало, надо установить [.NET Core 3.1 Runtime](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download).

- **Self-contained** = самодостаточный
- **Framework Development** = зависимый от фреймворка

Больше информации можно найти [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs).

Comment: Вопрос, а нельзя как то убавить занимаемое место для режима self-contained

Comment: @Viannedi [вот](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/deploying/trim-self-contained), но это уже другой вопрос. Если я ответил на ваш вопрос, пожалуйста отметьте ответ принятым.