# Как запустить код через терминал, а не встроенный терминал в IDE

Tags: c#, .net-core

Есть простой Hello World на c#, но мне нужно, чтобы он открылся через cmd, я пробовал вводить в командную строку расположение фала, но он открывает его в том же IDE (у меня Project Rider). Подскажите, как мне запустить его через консоль, мне нужно, чтобы он в отдельном окне открывался.

Comment: Если вы покажете, что именно вы вводите в командную строку, станет понятнее, но сдется мне что это путь к `sln` файлу, вам нужен `exe` файл из папки `bin/Debug` внутри каталога с проектом.

Comment: Открыл по этой директории (debug/exe), выдало это: A fatal error occurred. The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found.
If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [C:\Users\Alex_05\Desktop\c#\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\].
I

Comment: .NET Core значит, уже лучше, тогда в студии меню Build - Publish - File - выберите каталог, куда публиковать сборку, далее [тип сборки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1189422/373567), и если Single File, то выберите разрядность win_x64 или win_x86. В целевой папке появится нужный экзешник. После нажатия на кнопку Publish.

Comment: В Build у меня только -Build Solution, - rebuild solution,  -clean solution, advanced build actions, -change solution configuratin, больше ничего нет

Comment: Как опция `dotnet dllname.dll` для скомпилированного проекта.

Answer (score -1):

Ну, не очень хороший вопрос, но вот решение.

Переходим на расположение вашего файла, там где виден этот **Foo.cs**, потом открываем **cmd** и вводим такую команду: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe Foo.cs`

Где **Foo.cs** - там название вашего HelloWorld кода. После этого у вас в этом же расположении создастся файл **Foo.exe**. Если вы не прописали в коде команду: `Console.ReadKey()`, то тогда если вы запустите **exe**-шник, то скорее всего, он резко закроется.

Если же вы про то, как открыть исходный код вашего файла, то вам нужно правой кнопкой мыши нажать на ваш файл -> выбрать **открыть в Блокноте**, либо же **Открыть с помощью**. Если вы сделали **второй** вариант, то тогда вам нужно найти из **установленных** программ ваш **Блокнот**